# Masking part of a string

Tags: python

So my question is, I have an assignment that needs to be solved.

I have a simple function:

```
def multiplicator(x, y):
    var1 = x * y
    return var1
```

I need to use this multiplicator to get this result in another function:

```
Enter: "5435843398429829"     output: "****************9829"
```

The last 4 digits in the input should not be masked, but the rest should be masked with a "#".

Comment: `multiplicator(x, y)` is essentially `x * y`. Now what happens if you multiply a string with an integer?

Comment: You could use it as `multiplicator('#', len(input)-4)` to generate a sequence of `#`, but this assignment does not make much sense IMHO.

Comment: Are you missing anything else from the question?

Comment: I'd go and ask for help, or read the course material.

Comment: There are 12 `#` symbols: `multiplicator('#', 12)`

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you for your reply. I know, I feel the same way. However, you solved the issue spot on!

Answer (score 14):

Let us store that number you want to mask in a variable called masked.

```
unmasked = str(unmasked)
masked = len(unmasked[:-4])*"#"+unmasked[-4:]
```

I hope this works.

Comment: "in a variable called masked" Didn't you mean `unmasked`? Also, this is not using the function...

Comment: @tobias_k The unmasked integer is stored in unmasked while the masked number is stored as a string in the variable masked.

Comment: `(len(unmasked)-4)` would be more logical than `len(unmasked[:-4])`

Comment: @khelwood Either way works, but yeah, len(unmasked)-4 is also good. Given that negative numbers multiplied with strings give empty strings, so this solves the case when the number is less than 1000.

Comment: @SVengat Yes, that makes sense, but in your initial sentence you say that you store "the number you **want** to mask" in `masked`, i.e. the unmasked one. No big issue really, I just think the wording is somewhat off.

Answer (score 4):

just implemented this, so I thought I'd drop this here:

> For Python >= 3.6 (uses f-strings)

```
from math import ceil

def mask_string(s, perc=0.6):
    mask_chars = ceil(len(s) * perc)
    return f'{"*" * mask_chars}{s[mask_chars:]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Good solution by Vengat, and this also works  with `rjust`.

```
def multiplicator(x, y):
    var1 = str(x * y)
    #################
    # masking
    #################
    masked = var1[-4:].rjust(len(var1),"#")
    return masked
```

Without masking in function

```
def multiplicator(x, y):
    return x * y


def masker(n):
    var1 = str(n)
    masked = var1[-4:].rjust(len(var1),"#")
    return masked
```

Comment: I think the OP didn't want to modify the `multiplicator` function.

Comment: yeah then OP can take the ` masked ` line out of the function.