# masking string and phone number for dataframe in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-masking

Here I am trying to mask a data frame/dataset which have columns both  integers and String values like this:

```
sno,Name,Type 1,Type 2,phonenumber
1,Bulbasaur,Grass,Poison,9876543212
2,Ivysaur,Grass,Poison,9876543212
3,Venusaur,Grass,Poison,9876543212
```

This is the code I am using,below code is working fine for string values it is masking well but for integers it is not masking:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "path/to/file"
columnname= "phonenumber"
valuetomask = "9876543212"

column_dataset1 = pd.read_csv(filename)

print(column_dataset1)


# if(choice == "True"):
#masking for particular string/number in a column
column_dataset1[columnname]=column_dataset1[columnname].mask(column_dataset1[columnname] == valuetomask,"XXXXXXXXXX")
print(column_dataset1)
# masking last four digits
column_dataset1[columnname]=column_dataset1[columnname].str[:-4]+"****"
print(column_dataset1)
```

The above code is perfectly working for strings but when I gave "phonenumber"(any integer value) column it is not working.

Note: I need to do full masking(whole value should be masked) and partial masking(i.e last three digits/characters or first three digits/characters from above file) for any file which is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your phone numbers to string and then try masking:

```
mask_len = 5 # length of digits to mask from right side
column_dataset1['phonenumber'] = (
    column_dataset1['phonenumber'].astype(str) # convert to string
        .str[:-mask_len]+"*" * mask_len # masking digits
)
```

Comment: I tried this but not able to mask data, can you please help in masking too

Comment: Masking is added. you can find comprehensive masking answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408105/masking-part-of-a-string/52408187

Answer (score 1):

Convert to `str` and replace last four digits:

```
>>> df['phonenumber'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\d{4}$' , '****', regex=True)

0    987654****
1    987654****
2    987654****
Name: phonenumber, dtype: object
```

Which is the same of what @babakfifoo suggested:

```
>>>  df['phonenumber'].astype(str).str[:-4] + '****'
0    987654****
1    987654****
2    987654****
Name: phonenumber, dtype: object
```