# How to mask with '_' a part of a string in python

Tags: python

It's for our class hangman game project, it's divided in many steps and the fourth one is :
**Objective :**

1. As in the previous stage, you should use the following word list: 'python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript'
2. Once the computer has chosen a word from the list, show its first 3 letters. Hidden letters should be replaced with hyphens ("-").

**Examples:**

Example 1

```
H A N G M A N Guess the word jav-: > java
You survived!
```

Example 2

```
H A N G M A N Guess the word pyt---: > pythia
You lost!
```

**My problem**

Here is my hint function witch is suppose to mask the characters after the third first one :

```
def hint(word: str) -> str:

    print(word)

    print(len(word))

    # for the debugging the replace function seem to replace an identified 'string' by another

    replaced = word.replace(word[3:], "-" * (len(word)-3))

    print(replaced)

    return replaced
```

It works with the other words (python, kotlin...) but when the word to guess is 'Java', it gives me as output "J-v-"

Comment: Why are you using `replace`?  You just want to concatenate the first 3 letters to a string of `-`s long enough to get the original length.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Masking part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408105/masking-part-of-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`word[3:]` returns an `a`.

`(len(word)-3)` returns `1`.

So you end up with each `a` being replaced with a hyphen:

```
"Java".replace('a', '-')` 

>>>J-v-
```

Instead avoid `replace()`. You can consider:

```
replaced = word[:3] + '-' * len(word[3:])
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, you don't have to use `str.replace`, just construct new string:

```py
words = ["python", "java", "kotlin", "javascript"]


def hint(word):
    return word[:3] + "-" * (len(word) - 3)


for w in words:
    print(w, hint(w))
```

Prints:

```
python pyt---
java jav-
kotlin kot---
javascript jav-------
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
word = "Java"
hiddenWord = word[:3]
hiddenWord += '-' * (len(word)-3)
```